# QGIS 3 - Model Designer - PostgreSQL execute and load SQL- Change output name

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I am using the Model Designer in QGIS to create a tool and I am using the **PostgreSQL execute and load SQL** algorithm to add my query.

The output is a layer loaded in QGIS named **SQL layer**.

Is there a way to change the output name?

I have tried the **rename layer** algorithm but with no luck.

Especially for multiple SQL queries -> outputs, renaming the output layer is essential.

Answer (score 3):

Use load layer in the project but it only works for model builder:

[image]
[image]